# Tool tip in modal window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I m havin a jqueryui modal form. and i m using jquery cluetip tool tip plugin but tool tip is not working in a proper way on modal window form.. this is the screen shot ...

Star is showing the place where tool tip must be there and arrows are showing the place where tool tip is showin.. can any body tell me how to figure this out..[Screen Shot http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/2808/78241472.png](http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/2808/78241472.png)

*Edit:* can anybody tell me how to increase the z index of clue tip tool tip...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i got it...
thnsk friends

```
 $.fn.cluetip.defaults = {  // set up default options
width:            275,      // The width of the clueTip
height:           'auto',   // The height of the clueTip
cluezIndex:       1970,       // Sets the z-index style property of the clueTip
positionBy:       'auto',   // Sets the type of positioning: 'auto', 'mouse','bottomTop', 'fixed'
topOffset:        15,       // Number of px to offset clueTip from top of invoking element
leftOffset:       15,
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling cluetip, give it a higher z-index the the dialog (1001 by default) like this:

```
$(selector).cluetip({cluezIndex: '1020'});
```

[You can see the full list of options here](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/#options)

Answer (score 0):

The cluetip plugin has a `cluetipClass` you can provide.  Use that to set a class that has the z-index you want.

```
$('selector').cluetip({ splitTitle: '|', arrows: true, dropShadow: true, 
    cluetipClass: 'classWithHighZIndex', showTitle: false,  
    onActivate: activateFunction});
```